# How to make item in list display automatically when cursor moves on it?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have made drop-down list using *"option"* in *"select"* tag. Now I want  option to be displayed in drop-down list without clicking on option menu. How can I do it?

```
<select class="dropdown" tabindex="8" name="navyOp" onchange="test(this);" data-settings='{"wrapperClass":"metro"}'>
    <option value="1">Student Of the year</option>
    <option value="2">jab tak hai jaan</option>
    <option value="3">3 Idiot</option>
    <option value="3">Chennai express</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value of your dropdown box by adding the `selected` keyword to one of your `<option>` elements:

```
<select class="dropdown" tabindex="8" name="navyOp" onchange="test(this);" data-settings='{"wrapperClass":"metro"}'>
    <option value="1" selected>Student Of the year</option>
    <option value="2">jab tak hai jaan</option>
    <option value="3">3 Idiot</option>
    <option value="3">Chennai express</option>
</select>
```

If you use this code, option 1 will be selected automatically.

For more info, have a look [at this page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you want to achieve, then. Could you add more details to your question, and maybe a screenshot of your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using hover (means taking your mouse cursor on the menu but not click on the menu) in CSS.
here's the link for the tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yz8dZsmLHQo